# How to get name of output stream (i.e, stderr, or stdout) in java?

Tags: java, outputstream

In Java, how can I find the name of the stream which is passed as an argument, provided the given stream is either `System.err` or `System.out`?

```
public String getStreamName(OutputStream arg0) {
    String streamName = ????;
    return "This is stream: " + streamName;
}
```

should return something like:

```
This is stream: System.err
```

I've tried `arg0.toString()`, but that doesn't seem useful, as the name returned is something like `java.io.PrintStream@71cb25` and changes with each run. If the name was fixed, I could just compare it with the known names for stdout and stderr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void printStreamName(OutputStream stream) {
    String streamName = "Other";

    if(stream instanceof PrintStream) {
        streamName = stream == System.err ? "System.err" : (stream == System.out ? "System.out" : "Other");
    }

    System.out.println("This is stream: " + streamName);
}
```

Comment: Use the `equals` method when comparing objects (even if you know it will be equivalent to `==`).

Comment: I don't want to. There should be only one System.out and System.err ever initialized per JVM!

Answer (score 3):

System.out and System.err are both instances of PrintStream. Print streams and output streams do not have properties that you could use to differentiate them.

The API docs show what is available:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html

In this case you can just check if it is == to either System.out or System.err:

```
if (arg0 == System.out) {

} else if (arg0 == System.err) {

} else {
   // it is another output stream
}
```

Comment: Use the `equals` method when comparing objects (even if you know it will be equivalent to `==`).

Comment: @A.R.S. That is pointless when you can't be sure an implementation of `equals` will always be provided. The `OutputStream` you get here could be a custom implementation which doesn't necessarily provide `equals` implementation.

Comment: @adarshr If `equals` has not been implemented it will default to the `equals` method of `Object` which will in turn default to `==`. This does not matter. Using `==` on objects *anywhere* and at *any time* can cause problems in the future as code is updated and so on. Although negative ramifications may not be immediately evident, it i best to use `equals`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the best solution, but it works.

```
public  String getStreamName(OutputStream arg0) {
    boolean lol = arg0.equals(System.err);
    String streamName;

    if(lol)  streamName = "System.err";
    else  streamName = "System.out";

    return "This is stream: " + streamName;
}
```

Edit :

```
public  String getStreamName(OutputStream arg0)
{
 return "This is stream: " + ((arg0.equals(System.err)) ? "System.err" : "System.out");
}
```